# React-native run-android DeviceException: Failed to establish session

Tags: android, debugging, react-native

This is the error message I received when I ran `react-native run-android`

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session

My AVD is my android-23 x86_64 emulator that I have working. I haven't yet connected my app's APK nor know how to connect that with the emulator.

Comment: When you run `adb devices`, what does it output?